Opacity not working when uploading to arXiv
I am uploading a .tex file with tikz figures to arXiv and the figures do not have the opacity when arXiv compiles the file. Here is a MWE
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,mathrsfs,xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\filldraw[blue,fill opacity=0.3] (-3,0) rectangle (3,6);
\draw[blue,fill opacity=0.9,ultra thick] (-3,0) rectangle (3,6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

and the output when I compile it on my computer:

When I process the .tex file on arXiv this is what I get:

Update: It appears that arxiv is using hlatex while I am using pdflatex

Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you checked the log-files?

@Mensch Yes. The only warning was (/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty

Add \pdfoutput=1 within the first five lines of the preamble to direct arXiv to use pdflatex

To extend @DaiBowen's comment: the default workflow on arXiv is latex -> ps -> pdf, where the intermediate postscript step does not support transparency. Thus, forcing latex to compile per \pdfoutput=1 solves this issue.

It doesn't work for me
